# Setting up Cookies with jquery with a w3schools example

Tags: jquery, cookies

p>I am trying to set up a cookie with jquery, I am using the example from w3schools as shown below. When running this example on the w3schools website it works fine, when trying to run it from my own computer (iMac) it does not work, any reason why?

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
setCookie('name', 'value', 1);
checkCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for cookies to work, you need a server. If you are working with Javascript, you probably feel comfortable with [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/). Just install a simple web server like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) like:

```
npm i -g http-server
```

Then run the server from the directory you have your `index.html` that contains this script like:

```
http-server
```

And that's it. Load the page (from http://localhost:8080) and it works.

Comment: what is the problem? can you provide more information about how it doesn't work? For example error messages from console? What does the web development panel show for your cookie?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript error. Does the error say which line has the syntax error?